# Excel: Merging rows into one row based on three common column values and arranging other values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this generated data to excel and want it to sort it like in the image below:

[image]

I will be grateful if anyone will help me find a solution.

I'm new to excel.

Comment: When it comes to organizing and summarizing data, a pivot table is usually a good way to start.

Comment: @andrewb thank you so much for the idea, but I tried the Pivot Table, and the punch type won't designate the time to its specified cells in a row. It randomizes the data.

or I just didn't use the Pivot Table correctly.

Comment: You should be able to do this fairly easily in Power Query (available in Excel 2010+ & Office 365) by grouping and then pivoting within each group. If you can't figure it out, post your data as text which can be copy/pasted. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @JohnCobain, for each user/date is there only 1 checkin/breakout/breakin/checkout? If more than one then I can see the pivot giving some data that looks odd. I would also move the punch type from rows to columns and make sure the pivot body is formated to time.

Comment: @gns100 you're right there is only 1 checkin/breakout/breakin/checkout per date and user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much to those who helped me figure out this problem.

I just created a pivot table and put the UserID and Date into Rows.
Then the Punch Type goes to the Columns and Data from Time goes to Values.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwJU6.png)